# Date Format is not working

Tags: php, date, datetime

i have a string that is like this `2012/10/12 10:03:46` (Year/Month/Day) format now i want to change its format to something like this `October 12, 2012 10:03 p.m` i have tried php's DateTime class but its not working:

```
<?php

 $date = new DateTime();
 $date->createFromFormat('Y/m/dd H:i:s', substr($suggestion->suggestion->created_at, 0,19));
 echo $date->format('d-m, y h:i A');

?>
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong and how can i correct it??

Comment: /dd rather than simply /d ?!?

Comment: What do you get with the code you provided?

Comment: what is 10:03:46 == 3:03 p.m ?? how ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have seen at least one notice something like "don't call static function in non-static context".

[`DateTime::createFomFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', substr($suggestion->suggestion->created_at, 0,19));
echo $date->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```

It's a static method and (as the name suggests) it *creates* a new instance of `DateTime`.

Comment: thanks mate it helped me also just a little edit and its all done and correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Comment: @PHPSeeker : Thanks 2 u also for ur kindness

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

 $date = new DateTime('2012/10/12 10:03:46');
 echo $date->format('d-M, y h:i:s A');


//output -  12-Oct, 12 10:03:46 AM
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$today = date("F j, Y h:i a"); // gives October 15, 2012 5:20 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$today = date("F j, Y g:i A"); // gives October 15, 2012 5:20 PM (g removes leading zeroes)
```

Your case

```
$date = new DateTime('2012/10/12 10:03:46');
echo $date->format('F j, Y h:i A'); // gives October 15, 2012 10:03 AM
```

Reference : [click](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)